# Почему в кросс-таблице в СКД не высчитывается значение 1С?

Tags: 1с

Я взял имена пользователей из справочника пользователей и взял все профили доступа из справочника профилей групп доступа. Также сделал вычисляемое значение `Статус` (пока что просто вызывается функция, которая возвращает `"Да"`).

В строки добавил профили, в колонки - пользователей. Это работает нормально. Но почему в остальных ячейках нет строки `"Да"`?

Проблема вряд ли в функции, она вызывается нормально (в общем модуле с экспротом).

[image]